# Error in Plotly choropleth graph when binning values

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter

I am trying to create a choropleth graph with usa counties and color by range. I'm creating bins of my values with qcut and i get the following error:

`TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()`

Although when i use the len() function i get a result

```
len(pd.qcut(us_counties.ec_county, q=10).astype(str))
3089
```

Below is my code.

```
fig = px.choropleth(us_counties,
                   geojson = counties,
                   locations = 'county',
                   color = pd.qcut(us_counties.ec_county, q=10).astype(str),
                   color_discrete_sequence = px.colors.sequential.RdBu.reverse,
                   scope = 'usa',
                   hover_name = 'county_name',
                   hover_data = {'county':True, 'ec_county':True})
```

UPDATE!!
When I removed the .reverse from the color palette it just worked. I don't have a clue why??

[image]

Comment: It should be `px.colors.sequential.RdBu_r` if you want it reversed... `.reverse()` (you also missed the `()`) is an *IN PLACE* function that returns `None`. Another alternative that would work is `reversed(px.colors.sequential.RdBu)`.

Comment: The error message was quite clear here... you were giving it a `builtin_function_or_method` instead of what it expected. `.reverse` is a `builtin_function_or_method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a string cannot be used to specify a color, set the class value obtained by the binning process. Specify a discrete color map for it. I applied your code based on the [example](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/#choropleth-map-using-geojson) in the reference since you didn't present any concrete data. Classify the unemployment rate into 10 classes and use the resulting class values as the new columns. Designate that column as a color.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

qcut, bins = pd.qcut(df.unemp, q=10, labels=[str(x) for x in np.arange(1,11,1)], retbins=True)
df['unemp_binning'] = qcut

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(df,
                    geojson=counties,
                    locations='fips',
                    color='unemp_binning',
                    color_discrete_sequence = px.colors.qualitative.Set1.reserve(),
                    scope="usa",
                    hover_name = 'fips',
                    hover_data = {'fips':True, 'unemp_binning':True},
                    labels = {'unemp':'unemployment classification'}
                          )
fig.update_traces(marker_line_color='darkgray')
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution but I kept getting the same error. Then i figured out that the problem was in color_discrete_sequence when using reverse color pallete. When I removed it, the figured appeared. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, it should be `.reverse()`. The code has been corrected and the graph updated.